# Problema con json (If else)

Tags: json, método

soy nuevo en esto de programar, y me he quedado atrapado aca. les explico tengo la siguiente función, que trabaja excelente y me muestra perfecto el json:.

```
String URL_JASON = "http://prueba/personajesEN.json";
private JsonArrayRequest ArrayRequest;
private RequestQueue requestQueue;
private ArrayList<personajes> lstAnime;
private RecyclerView recyclerView;
```

me carga el json perfecto, el detalle es que he credo otro json con otro idioma, y he creado la siguiente función para que al detectar el Lenguaje del dispositivo utilice o un Json o otro json, pero no logro que me corra.

```
String idioma;
String URL_JASON;


private void prueba (){

    if (idioma.equals ("es_US"))
    { URL_JASON = "http://prueba/personajesES.json";

} else {

    URL_JASON = "http://prueba/personajesEN.json";
    }

}


private JsonArrayRequest ArrayRequest;
private RequestQueue requestQueue;
private ArrayList<personajes> lstAnime;
private RecyclerView recyclerView;
```

Me salta el error: Private method 'prueba()' es never used

Me gustaria saber que estoy realizando mal. Muy probable que se ha de otra manera que se realice el uso del If y else para verificar el idioma y eso. De verdad necesito la ayuda de un experto en la materia.

Otra cosita ese codijo esta metido en un Fragment.

Puede ser tambien que este utilizando mal el metodo en el fragment. De antemano gracias por la ayuda.

Comment: Hola, podrías agregar el código de tú clase completa para comprender mejor tú problema.

Answer (score 2):

El mensaje que te da :`Private method 'prueba()' es never used` es debido a que declaras una función llamada `prueba()` pero luego nunca la llamas.

Una forma en la que puedes realizar lo que te propones es usando el operador condicional ternario, de esta manera no necesitas crear una función.

El operador ternario `condition ? if true : if false` funciona como un `if else` compacto, que se usa normalmente para casos como el que tu planteas.

El operador trabaja de la siguiente forma:

1. `condition` es el argumento que vamos a estudiar, debe ser un valor booleano o una expresión que devuelva un booleano. Por ejemplo, `idioma.equals("es_ES");` devuelve un valor `true` o un valor `false`. El argumento debe ir seguido de un signo de interrogación. `condition ?`
2. `if true` es la sentencia que ejecutaremos si la condición analizada devuelve `true`. Debe ir seguida de un doble punto `:`.
3. `if false` es la sentencia que se ejecutará en caso que la condición analizada devuelve `false`.

En este caso, usaremos el operador ternario para asignarle un valor una variable.

**PROBLEMA**

Se desea asignar un valor a una variable tipo `string` que almacena una URL que apunta a un archivo JSON. Dependiendo del idioma del sistema, la URL apuntará a un archivo con idioma español o a un archivo con idioma inglés.

**SOLUCIÓN**

Para tomar la decisión de acuerdo al idioma del sistema usaremos el operador condicional ternario, de la siguiente manera: `String URL_JSON = idioma.equals("es_ES") ? "http://prueba/personajesES.json" : "http://prueba/personajesEN.json";`

El código podría quedar de la siguiente manera:

```
String URL_JSON = idioma.equals("es_ES") ? "http://prueba/personajesES.json" : "http://prueba/personajesEN.json";
private JsonArrayRequest ArrayRequest;
private RequestQueue requestQueue;
private ArrayList<personajes> lstAnime;
private RecyclerView recyclerView;
```

Estamos asumiendo que la variable idioma contiene un string de la forma "es_ES".

Espero que esto te ayude a resolver el problema.

Si usas JAVA, aquí un enlace a [Operadores Condicionales - Java](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/op2.html)

Comment: VinotintoPlayer, si esta respuesta resolvió tu problema, puedes [aceptar la respuesta](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/accepted-answer). Saludos.